# Abandoned cart email Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby the customer should be sent a mail after a certain time of abandoning the cart.
Is there some out of the box functionality in Hybris to achieve this or we would have to build our own logic?

Answer (score 3):

There is no OOTB solution for abandoned cart email, you can check CartRemovalJob source code for finding carts and ticket event emails source code and templates for sending localized emails.

Comment: @myksoft,thanks a lot for your comment.How do I share the link of the customer's cart with them?I mean is the /cart url different for different customer?

Comment: System has only one cart url. Spring detect user with cookies and auto load her session then show her cart. If cookie missing, user see login screen or empty cart.

Comment: @myksoft,so to ensure that registered customer only access their carts,should we prompt them to a new web service,which prompts them for login.

Comment: Generally we don't need login for displaying cart. There is no security issue. Every user only can show their cart. There is login need for address and payment step. Also yolu can change it for forcing login.

Comment: @myksoft,it might also happen that I am registered on a site with my credentials.However, this time I am browsing the site as an anonymous user and have added the item in my cart.When I get a mail to the /cart service for rendering the cart page,it will be the anonymous user's cart but it should ideally be the registered customer's cart.

Comment: May be login page has redirect query param, I am not sure now. If not, you can create new path with forcelogin annotation for using in email. If user add some items in anonymous mode, they get question about cart merge.